# Unexpected output from two functions/classes

Tags: javascript

I expected this javascript code to print "a".
This javascript code prints "b".

```js
function newA() {
 this.doSomething = function() {console.log("a");}
 return this;
}

function newB() {
 this.doSomething = function() {console.log("b");}
 return this;
}

const a = newA();
const b = newB();
a.doSomething();
```

```
test.js:7 b
```

It still prints "b" if the order that `newA` and `newB` are declared in is switched.
I don't know why this is happening and I can't phrase my problem well enough to Google an explanation.

Comment: The way you call the functions, `this` refers to the global object. You are basically creating a global variable `doSomething`. The second function call will always override that variable. `a === window`. If you put your code into strict mode you would get an error. You are not actually using the functions as "classes".

Comment: Try `new newA()` and `new newB()` to see the expected behaviour ....